# configure qmake project file to include private header

Tags: qt, qmake

I found brief answers to this online telling me to simply add `QT += [gui/widgets/core]-private` but it still didn't work. The 2 headers I want to include specifically are [qcssparser_p.h](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/067b53864112c084587fa9a507eb4bde3d50a6e1/src/gui/text/qcssparser_p.h) and [qstylesheetstyle_p.h](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/067b53864112c084587fa9a507eb4bde3d50a6e1/src/widgets/styles/qstylesheetstyle_p.h). How would I set up qmake or even a regular makefile to include these 2 files?

Answer (score 1):

Package name :

qtbase5-private-dev

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33465840)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's stuck on this like me, if you're on linux you need to install the `qt5base-private-dev` package to use private headers. If you've done that and you have

```
QT += gui-private
QT += widgets-private
QT += core-private
```

in your .pro file than everything should work